# how to import com.amazonaws.util.Throwables.failure

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk

I have in an awkward situation. I am trying to import `com.amazonaws.util.Throwables.failure`. I can autocomplete up to Throwables.  But, I cannot find `failure` under `Throwables`.  How can I import `com.amazonaws.util.Throwables.failure`?

I may have to define the dependency in `build.gradle`.  But, don't know what I should define.

Thanks a lot for your advice.

Comment: `failure` is probably a method in `com.amazonaws.util.Throwables`. Could you check the source?

Comment: @Edric Thanks for the comment.  What source should I check?

Comment: Hi Aniruddh Parlhar, the reason why I rollbacked to the 1st version of this question is that "may have" is not actually the same as "need". The OP probably meant that he "might have" to define a dependency as in it is now a must to define the dependency, as compared to "need", which completely changes the meaning of the sentence.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you're trying to import a method from a class. I don't think that's possible in Java, so what you have to do is to just import `com.amazonaws.utils.Throwables` and then access the `failure` method from the imported `Throwables` class:

```java
import com.amazonaws.utils.Throwables;
// ...

// NOTE: This is dummy/sample/example code. Please implement your own version of whatever you're doing.
private void throwFailure() {
    // blah blah blah
    Throwables.failure(/* insert parameters here */);
    // blah blah blah
}
```

Comment: My code is `import static com.amazonaws.utils.Throwables.failure`.  It seems allow me to import the method.  Anyway I tried as you suggested with 'import static com.amazonaws.utils.Throwables', and created `throwFailure`.  But Android Studio says that Throwables does not have the method of `failure`, but it does only `getRootCause`, `values`, `valueOf`

Comment: I have got the meaning of your comment of "check the source'.  I checked the code of `com.amazonaws.utils.Throwables`.  Strangely it is different from the code I found in github.  The code which my code reference, ofc, does not have the method of failure, but the github source code of `com.amazonaws.utils.Throwables` does have the method.

Comment: Note that the `throwFailure` function is just dummy code. I'm not experienced with Amazon's AWS.